# Jfxtra window bring it forward / internal window

Tags: javafx

I have an internal `jfxtra` window. On clicking a button, I want to bring it forward.

The code that I have tried :

```
window w = new window("mdi win");
private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

...

public void win() {

Parent bla = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("bla.fxml"));
w.getContentPane().getChildren().add(bla);
rootLayout.getChildren().add(w);
}

private void wfront(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
  w.isMoveToFront(); // is not?
}
```

How to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you made me curious and I went through the JFXtras docs. I came to know that Window in Jfxtras extends `Control`. So there is a method called `toFront` which can be fired on it. To show this I have created a sample for you.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jfxtras.scene.control.window.Window;

public class NewWindow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button("Click Me to show Window !");
        Window window = new Window("Cick Me to bring me to front");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    window.toFront();
                    window.setTitle("I am on the Front");
                }
        });

        window.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(window, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Let me know, if you are looking for something else !

Comment: This method (window) permits clicks. i want to with a click of the button,  window to come forward

Comment: the method `wfront` is called on the click of a button. Isn't it ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/efiso6o2jp7wv5s/xtrawin.zip?dl=0 netbeans project + libs

Comment: I can't go through your project, but I have made a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which might help you

Comment: no project just jxtra windows example, As a convenience to you :)

Comment: if its just a demo, add the class to your question